# Where can I get an air compressor that can blow air (not just inflate tires)?

Tags: cleaning, product-recommendation, compressor, blower

I have been able to find [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003XGYDE2)

[image]

and [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000E4BW7W),

[image]

but they don't come with the fitting/handle that allows you to blow air - for instance, if you want to blow dust from your keyboard, etc.

Does anyone know if [this kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0017JSD34)

[image]

will fit any of those pumps?

Or if not, what other small, portable, air compressors are there that can do what I want (also, I DO want to inflate tires - just not ONLY).

Comment: Yes, those will fit together; but you're missing a piece. Most people purchase a quick-connect fitting and screw into the back of the blower, so it can be easily swapped on/off the compressor hose. They don't come with that fitting pre-attached, because some people have different size hose & fittings, or may want to permanently attach the blower to a hose. Really, any compressor can fit any hose, can fit any tool; if you get the right fittings. Whether the compressor provides enough air to power the tool is a different question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that may make some sense on several levels. Buy an air tank. I have a moderately big one, that holds 10 gallons of air. Of course, it is heavy to carry around, being steel. But when I need to pump up a tire beyond the range of the several hundred feet of hose I have, or for whatever use I need, I just disconnect it from my compressor lines where I have it coupled with a quick disconnect.

In your case, my suggestion is to pump it up with a foot pump. :) Ok, yes, this will take some work, but once pumped up, it will keep that air under pressure until you want it. And since you are looking for a "green" solution, this is as green as you can imagine, using foot power. Or, I suppose you could always just go to the local service station and pump it up to 100 PSI or so. Once the valve is shut, it will maintain that pressure for a long time.

Fix up a short length of air hose so you can use it to blow air. One of those plastic spiral air hoses might be perfect, allowing you about 20 feet of walking distance.

An even cheaper solution is to just buy a truck tire inner tube. Pep Boys sells them for about $15. Go to the gas station to pump it up, and then you can carry it anywhere you want, for a ready source of compressed air that weighs very little to carry around. Again, you will need to figure out how to put a line on the tire valve, but this is not hard to do. Go to your local hardware store and they should be able to get you set up. (I did not say to go to Lowes or Home Depot, but to go to a store where they actually understand hardware.)

EDIT:

Then here is what I'd do. The first part will be to put a hose onto an inner tube. I don't know what thread an inner tube valve is, so I would go to my local hardware store and get them to help me find a nipple with the proper thread. They tend to stock entire shelves of them, so this is not a real problem. Once you have that, you need to be able to couple it to a 1/4 inch NPT (National Pipe Thread.) This is a standard thread for air hoses and the like.  When you add the coupling to the tire valve, you will need to remove the needle valve inside. This will allow air to go freely in and out of the tire tube.

Next, add an [Air line ball valve](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HI7JNY). This will let you shut off the air positively, because you want it to stay pumped up. Notice that the threads on the ball vavle are 1/4 inch NPT, exactly what you need.

[image]

Next, I went to Amazon and typed in "coiled air hose" into the search field. Typically, these run from $10 - $30, depending on the length of the hose. I find they work nicely, giving me an extensible hose. You don't need a long one though.

[image]

Finally, I looked online for a quick connect coupler. Central Pneumatic or Campbell Hausfeld  are common names here. The quick connect coupler will allow you to easily attach a handheld air blow gun as you show. Note that it will have a 1/4 inch NPT thread! You can also attach a regular tire valve, to use that to blow up your reserve of compressed air, using either foot pump or a gas station pump.

[image]

All of these items are common things you will find in any local hardware store, or even most auto parts stores.

Of course, the amount of air you can put into such a tube is somewhat limited, but it will easily be sufficient to keep a keyboard clean. You can put far more into a steel air tank, because you can store higher pressures there.

Comment: As an added bonus. If it snows where you are, you can use the inner tube to go tubing!

Comment: This is brilliant. This makes total sense too....because the thing is, I don't live in the US. So I was going to buy it online and ship it to a friend who is coming down. Now, though, I might just buy the hose and the attachments I need and go that route. Thanks!

P.S. Any suggestions for hoses?

Comment: P.S. My desire to not use a depletable resource is not really for 'green' purposes. It's coupled with being frugal and hating waste (although, you can argue that's 'green'). But I love this solution, really do.

Comment: There are a lot of things we can do that simply make sense. Is it green to do something in a non-wasteful way? Composting for example, is something I have learned to love. Rather than throwing away kitchen waste, I compost as much as I can, then use that compost next spring.

Comment: My only question is, if I get an air tank, how do I know when it reaches full capacity when filling it. I don't want to burst it...should that even be a concern?

Comment: >The first part will be to put a hose onto an inner tube. I don't know what thread an inner tube valve is, so I would go to my local hardware store and get them to help me find a nipple with the proper thread. 
Would I need to do that if I am using a tank? It sounds like that would be a tire, no?

Comment: An air tank will usually be threaded for 1/4"" NPT already, so that part is done if you get a tank. As well, it will probably have a shut-off valve, so that is also done. As far as the capacity goes, a steel tank for air will probably be rated for 125 PSI at least. When you fill it using a gas station pump, the pump has a pressure gauge on it - you set the desired pressure. Likewise, even a foot pump would have that, though a foot pump would take a rather long time to pump that much air.

Comment: BTW, the air tank is a perfect solution for many problems. A friend of mine uses his for painting models with an air brush.

Comment: @woodchips you are absolutely right. That solution is brilliant. I am definitely going to use it.

Comment: But don't leave the air tank to rust in the wet corner of your garage when you're not using it. Another name for a rusty air tank filled with high pressure air is "bomb" -- keep it clean and dry.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something smaller than this?

[Porter Cable Pancake Air Compressor](http://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200197024_200197024)

[image]

To get any kind of are pressure / volume, you need a compressor of a decent size.  Those little mini compressors can inflate something, but it takes a long time and they don't have the volume of air necessary to blow dust.

Comment: That does look like something I would want, but it's way too bulky and expensive. Is there nothing smaller that I can get my hands on, within the price range of the others?

Comment: I am not dusting anything like a car...it literally is my computer (keyboard and inside the case + my hobby R/C car). I would just buy a canister of compressed air, but I hate the thought of depleting a non-renewable resource (i.e. I will have to buy a new can after X number of sprays). I would rather get something that just requires electricity to be renewed.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using a [small shopvac](http://www.homedepot.com/Tools-Hardware-Wet-Dry-Vacuums/h_d1/N-5yc1vZb8pi/R-202198493/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) instead of an air compressor, for several reasons.

- Air from compressors contains moisture which can harm electronics.
- If you want anything more than a few seconds of air, you'll need a compressor with a high [CFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_feet_per_minute) output or a large tank. This means more money than you're willing to spend. I've got this [1 gal. compressor](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-202019874/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053), and it's awesome for trim work and filling up tires, but nearly worthless for blowing off work surfaces.
- Not only would you need to buy a compressor, but you'd also need to buy a [hose](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100668714/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) and all the [accessories](http://www.homedepot.com/Tools-Hardware-Air-Compressors-Tools-Accessories-Air-Tool-Accessories-Hoses/h_d1/N-5yc1vZbb3n/R-203009769/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053), which means even more money.

It's true, you can't use a shopvac for filling up tires, but you can use it for plenty of other things around the house anyway.

Comment: You're not suppose to use a vacuum for cleaning the inside of a computer because it generates alot of static electricity. Or at least, that's what they say.

Comment: @Doresoom +1 for the moisture warning.

Comment: I agree with the comment about static electricity. I understand the concern about moisture, and what I will do is leave the computer open so the moisture dries. This is a good suggestion though.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to need something with a storage tank.  The little "inflater" type compressors basically use the tire, ball, etc. as the storage tank. Because of this, they are not going to be able to blow air with any force.

If you're just looking to blow dust from your keyboard, why not use compressed gas in a can?

[image]

*don't try to fill your tires with this.*

If you are dead set on using a compressor for this, you're going to want to look for a small 1 - 3 gallon compressor.  Though, you may find even the smallest compressor is overkill (unless the keyboard is *really* dusty). You should be able to find a 1 gallon compressor online for ~$100.00, just make sure you get one that is *oil-free* if you are going to be using it on keyboards and whatnot.

Comment: This is what I usually use...but, I don't want to have to keep buying a new can when I use it. I want to find a small machine that will function just like this. You are absolutely right about the tank - which is why I came here to find out if anyone knew of any suggestions :)

Comment: @marcamillion for what you're going to use it for, a high end compressor probably does not make sense.  You also don't want the cheapest piece of crap you can find. Look for something middle of the road, from a company you've heard of (Porter Cable, DeWalt, Hitachi, Senco, etc.).

Comment: that's exactly what I am trying to do - except I don't know the companies to look for.....it's why I am here :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to blow air you need a tank, you could DIY something with soda bottles or balloons (beware of over inflating)

however cheap hand operated [keyboard blowers](http://www.suntekstore.com/goods-10002762-Air+Blower+Keyboard+LCD+Screen+Cleaner+for+HP+Laptop.html) exist (google link no affiliation)

and a bicycle pump can inflate car tires (if the valve fits on mountain bikes it'll fit on cars) remember that cars need a much lower pressure (~30 psi) compared to bikes (50-75 psi)

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for an alternative solution to canned air when I ran across your question. An alternative solution might be an airbrush compressor.  I figure you could attach a standard blower thing like pictured above.